# Initializing data with Openmp [shallow water algorithm]

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

First of all, my Englishg level sucks, so sorry if something isn't well written...

I'm learning how to parallelize C code using OpenMP, the algorith I'm trying to parallelize is the shallow water equations algorithm, and although with a simple `#pragma omp parallel for` in the most critical loop I've gained nearly 40% more performance I know that my implementation is very poor and I'm not milking the cores as I should. The structure of the code is simple: a 'main' that allocates memory and initializes some matrixes and arrays and calls a function called solver that does all the work, where I putted the `#pragma omp parallel for`.

I was thinking that I could boost the performance using a parallel section where the memory is allocated and initialized so every thread has all the data, but when i run the program I don't have any boost, and since I'm a rookie with this I don't know if my thinking was bad or the bad thing was my implementation. I'll apreciate some help or a hint that could boost the performance of the algorithm. This is my homework and I don't want someone to do it for me, just a little help that can make me go forward...

---

I'll paste the code for better understanding:

MAIN FUNCTION (Allocations and initializations)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  long int i, j, m, n, M, N;
  char *ptr;
  long int s;
  int flag, verbose;
  double *Q;
  double *x, *y;
  double **ffx, **nFx, **ffy, **nFy;
  double dx, dt, epsi, delta, dy, tend, tmp, stime;

 /* Default values to use: m volumes in the x-direction and n volumes in the y-direction    
  M = 1000;
  N = 1000;

  /* create file and verbose flags */
  .......
  .......

  /* Parse command line options */
  .......
  .......


  epsi = 2.0;
  delta = 0.5;
  dx = (xend - xstart) / (double) M;
  dy = (yend - ystart) / (double) N;
  dt = dx / sqrt( 9.81 * 5.0);
  tend = 0.1;

  /* Add two ghost volumes at each side of the domain */
  m = M + 2;
  n = N + 2;

  /* Allocate memory for the domain */

  /*HERE IS WHRE I PUT THE PRAGMA FOR PARALLEL INITIALIZATION AND    ALLOCATIONS*/
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
  Q = (double *) malloc(m * n * cell_size *  sizeof(double));

  x = (double *) malloc(m * sizeof(double));
  y = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));    

  /* Allocate memory for fluxes */
  ffx = (double **) malloc(cell_size * sizeof(double *));
  ffy = (double **) malloc(cell_size * sizeof(double *));
  nFx = (double **) malloc(cell_size * sizeof(double *));
  nFy = (double **) malloc(cell_size * sizeof(double *));

  ffx[0] = (double *) malloc(cell_size * m * sizeof(double));
  nFx[0] = (double *) malloc(cell_size * m * sizeof(double));
  ffy[0] = (double *) malloc(cell_size * n * sizeof(double));
  nFy[0] = (double *) malloc(cell_size * n * sizeof(double));

  for (i = 0; i < cell_size; i++) {
    ffx[i] =  ffx[0] + i * m;
    nFx[i] =  nFx[0] + i * m;
    ffy[i] =  ffy[0] + i * n;
    nFy[i] =  nFy[0] + i * n;
  }

  for (i = 0,tmp= -dx/2 + xstart; i < m; i++, tmp += dx)
    x[i] = tmp;

  for (i = 0,tmp= -dy/2 + ystart; i < n; i++, tmp += dy)
    y[i] = tmp;

  /* Set initial Gauss hump */
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      Q(0, i, j) = 4.0;
      Q(1, i, j) = 0.0;
      Q(2, i, j) = 0.0;
    }
  }

  for (i = 1; i < m-1; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < n-1; j++) {
      Q(0, i, j) = 4.0 + epsi * exp(-(pow(x[i] - xend / 4.0, 2) + pow(y[j] - yend / 4.0, 2)) /
                      (pow(delta, 2)));
    }
  }
  }

  //  Record start time
  stime = gettime();
  /*THIS IS THE FUNCTION WHERE THE 'WORK' IS DONE*/
  solver(Q, ffx, ffy, nFx, nFy, m, n, tend, dx, dy, dt);`
}
```

SOLVER FUNCTION (Critical Section)

```
/*
  This is the main solver routine. 
*/
void solver(double *Q, double **ffx, double **ffy, double **nFx, double **nFy,
        int m, int n, double tend, double dx, double dy, double dt) {
  double bc_mask[3] = {1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
  double time;
  int i, j, k, steps;

  steps = ceil(tend / dt);  
  for (i = 0, time = 0.0; i < steps; i++, time += dt) { 

    /* Apply boundary condition */ 
    #pragma omp parallel for private(j) num_threads (NTHR)
    for (k = 0; k < cell_size; k++)    
    {
      for (j = 1; j < n - 1 ; j++)  
      {
    Q(k, 0, j) = bc_mask[k] *  Q(k, 1, j);
    Q(k, m-1, j) = bc_mask[k] *  Q(k, m-2, j);
      }
    }
    #pragma omp parallel for private(j) num_threads (NTHR)
    for (k = 0; k < cell_size; k++)  
    {
      for (j = 0; j < m; j++) 
      {
    Q(k, j, 0) = bc_mask[k] * Q(k, j, 1);
    Q(k, j, n-1) = bc_mask[k] * Q(k, j, n-2);
      }
    }

    /* Update all volumes with the Lax-Friedrich's scheme */     
    laxf_scheme_2d(Q, ffx, ffy, nFx, nFy, m, n, dx, dy, dt);  

  }
}

/*
  This is the Lax-Friedrich's scheme for updating volumes
*/
void laxf_scheme_2d(double *Q, double **ffx, double **ffy, double **nFx, double **nFy,
            int m, int n, double dx, double dy, double dt) {
  int i, j, k;

  /* Calculate and update fluxes in the x-direction */
  #pragma omp parallel for private(k,j) num_threads (NTHR)
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    fx(Q, ffx, m, n, i);
    for (k = 0; k < cell_size;  k++) 
      for (j = 1; j < m; j++)
    nFx[k][j] = 0.5 * ((ffx[k][j-1] + ffx[k][j]) - dx/dt * (Q(k, j, i) - Q(k, j-1, i)));
    for (k = 0; k < cell_size;  k++) 
      for (j = 1; j < m-1; j++)
    Q(k, j, i) = Q(k, j, i)  - dt/dx * ((nFx[k][j+1] - nFx[k][j]));

  }

  /* Calculate and update fluxes in the y-direction */
  #pragma omp parallel for private(k,j) num_threads (NTHR)
  for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    fy(Q, ffy, m, n, i);
    for (k = 0; k < cell_size; k++)
      for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
    nFy[k][j] = 0.5 * ((ffy[k][j-1] + ffy[k][j]) - dy/dt * (Q(k, i, j) - Q(k, i, j -1)));
    for (k = 0; k < cell_size; k++)
      for (j = 1; j <  n-1; j++) 
    Q(k,i,j) = Q(k,i,j) -  dt/dy * ((nFy[k][j+1]  -  nFy[k][j]));
  }

}
```

As I understand there is no data dependency in the loops of the solver function and it's sub-functions, and since putting a parallel region in the allocation and data initialization did nothing, I don't know how to continue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, I do not think that making the initialization phase parallel is going to bring you any gain, as with these type of codes nearly all time is spent in the solvers. Second, just using a parallel region without giving OpenMP any information what to does not bring anything. You need to distribute tasks.

Comment: What does `Q(k, j, n)` mean? `Q` is a pointer to double, i.e., it can be treated as a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @DanielLangr I think he has some nasty `#define`s written above that allow him to access Q with 3D-like notation...

Comment: There is this #define Q(i, j, k) Q[((k) + n * ((j) + m * (i)))]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code. First of all, you have data races there, since you write to shared variables, such as `Q`, `x`, and `y`, by **all threads**. Either do the allocations outside of a parallel region or perform them by a single thread only (`#pragma omp master` or `#pragma omp single`).

Then, you don't parallelize the `for` loops in the initialization section. In fact, all these loops are executed by all threads within whole ranges (again with data races and likely a lot of cache contention). You should add `#pragma omp parallel` to these loops. For nested loops, the `collapse` directive might be useful.

Also, be sure that there are no data races in `solver()` and `laxf_scheme_2d()` functions. Seemingly, the most time of the calculation is spend within `laxf_scheme_2d()`, however, this function is not at all run in parallel. Does it use OpenMP internally?

Comment: I'm very rusty with programming. For understanding the data races in the `laxf_scheme_2d` function, wich is the heaviest (I putted it on a comment), seeing the allocations in the main I have to take Q (that has that nasty  `#define Q(i, j, k) Q[((k) + n * ((j) + m * (i)))]` above) has a 3D array accessed by pointers right? and `ffx` as a one dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. I've seen many problems in my implementation, first of all the heaviest function where all the job is done is `laxf_scheme_2d`. 
About the `Q` variable i have this `#define Q(i, j, k) Q[((k) + n * ((j) + m * (i)))]`

This is `laxf_scheme_2d`

```
void laxf_scheme_2d(double *Q, double **ffx, double **ffy, double **nFx, double **nFy,
            int m, int n, double dx, double dy, double dt) {
  int i, j, k;

  /* Calculate and update fluxes in the x-direction */
  #pragma omp for
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    fx(Q, ffx, m, n, i);
    for (j = 1; j < m; j++) 
      for (k = 0; k < cell_size;  k++) 
    nFx[k][j] = 0.5 * ((ffx[k][j-1] + ffx[k][j]) -
               dx/dt * (Q(k, j, i) - Q(k, j-1, i)));
    for (j = 1; j < m-1; j++)
      for (k = 0; k < cell_size;  k++) 
    Q(k, j, i) = Q(k, j, i)  - dt/dx * ((nFx[k][j+1] - nFx[k][j]));

  }

  /* Calculate and update fluxes in the y-direction */
  #pragma omp for
  for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    fy(Q, ffy, m, n, i);
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
      for (k = 0; k < cell_size; k++)
    nFy[k][j] = 0.5 * ((ffy[k][j-1] + ffy[k][j]) - 
               dy/dt * (Q(k, i, j) - Q(k, i, j -1)));
    for (j = 1; j <  n-1; j++) 
      for (k = 0; k < cell_size; k++)
    Q(k,i,j) = Q(k,i,j) -  dt/dy * ((nFy[k][j+1]  -  nFy[k][j]));
  }

}
```

Functions `fx` and `fy` are very simple and with no data dependencies. I can't put de `#pragma omp parallel for` above the first `for` loop because there are data races but for now I can't see how to change this code to overcome them.

```
long int i, j, m, n, M, N;
  char *ptr;
  long int s;
  int flag, verbose;
  double *Q;
  double *x, *y;
  double **ffx, **nFx, **ffy, **nFy;
  double dx, dt, epsi, delta, dy, tend, tmp, stime;
  M = 1000;
  N = 1000;

/* Add two ghost volumes at each side of the domain */
  m = M + 2;
  n = N + 2;

  /* Allocate memory for the domain */
  Q = (double *) malloc(m * n * cell_size *  sizeof(double));

  x = (double *) malloc(m * sizeof(double));
  y = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));    

  /* Allocate memory for fluxes */
  ffx = (double **) malloc(cell_size * sizeof(double *));
  ffy = (double **) malloc(cell_size * sizeof(double *));
  nFx = (double **) malloc(cell_size * sizeof(double *));
  nFy = (double **) malloc(cell_size * sizeof(double *));

  ffx[0] = (double *) malloc(cell_size * m * sizeof(double));
  nFx[0] = (double *) malloc(cell_size * m * sizeof(double));
  ffy[0] = (double *) malloc(cell_size * n * sizeof(double));
  nFy[0] = (double *) malloc(cell_size * n * sizeof(double));
```